# No editor in Eclipse to open Java files with?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I had to reinstall Eclipse on my computer due to an upgrade; now it seems to have "forgotten" how to open and edit Java files. When I first opened a .java file, my system text editor popped up. I tried reinstalling Eclipse; same behaviour. I tried removing the .metadata files from my workspace; same behaviour. I tried changing the .java file association and tried using the system and default editors; same behaviour. I tried opening it with all internal editors just to see if that might help - Default Compare Editor, Internal Web Broswer, No Source Found, Source Not Found Editor, Text Editor, Web Browser, and Welcome - but to no avail. There are no error messages; it's as if my ability to open Java files in Eclipse has simply disappeared. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about right click > Open with > Java editor?

If there is no Java editor, then your eclipse installation is messed up - get a new one from eclipse.org

Comment: If that means my installation is messed up then my installation is indeed messed up. I'll try and get one from eclipse.org and tell you how it goes.

Comment: Yep, my installation was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: What is meant by "get a new one from eclipse.org"?  I am having this same problem.